# Disable blank page in iframe while loading another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

`<iframe src="a_search_page.php" width="100%"></iframe>`

If you ever used a slow connection **in mobile devices**, you may have noticed a blank white page appears while loading another page (usually appears, even in rapid connection). I mean if the user enter something & click on the Search in my website, it sends data to the server & since the server oppositely sends data to the user, a blank white page appears **in mobile devices** until the user recieves `HTML` data fully.

I want to disable the blank white page between loading of another page.
I want not to show the white blank page, I want it to be frozen while loading another page. I mean when the user clicks on Search, the current page to be frozen until the user recieves `HTML` data of Search Result page fully!

So, can I do this using `JavaScript`/`jQuery`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for?

```
<script>
   var firstrun = new Object();
   function frameMagic(el) {
   if (typeof firstrun[el] === ‘undefined’) { firstrun[el]=true; }
   else { document.getElementById(el).scrollIntoView(); }
   }
</script>
<iframe id=”iframe” onLoad=”frameMagic(‘iframe’);”>
```

Comment: No. It behaves almost same/same.